# Data com dia a menos no MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jpa

estou com um probleminha chato que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em java usando Spring Framework e usando VueJS como front. O banco de dados é MySQL.

O problema é que quando tento salvar uma data igual ou anterior à 16/02/2019, a data é salva com 1 dia menos no MySQL. Se for uma data posterior a essa, a data é salva corretamente.

edit: Percebi que no ano de 2020 também ocorre esse problema, parece ser algo relacionado a esse período de 01/01 até 16/02.

edit2: Percebi que o problema começa em Novembro, a partir de 05/11. Ou seja, qualquer data que eu tentar salvar entre 05/11 e 16/02, é salva no banco com o dia anterior. Se não estiver nesse período, a data é salva normalmente.

Já confirmei que a data chega correta no java, então o problema não está no VueJS. E verifiquei também que antes de fazer a chamada para salvar a entidade através do JpaRepository, a data ainda está correta, então creio que seja problema no MySQL, ou alguma configuração que precisa ser feita no Spring.

Já mexi nas configurações do arquivo de propriedades do Spring usando essas propriedades:

- spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=America/Sao_Paulo
- user.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo

Porém nenhuma delas resolveu o problema.

Alguém consegue me ajudar aí? Vlw!

Comment: Posta o trecho de codigo q salva a data no banco pfvr.

Comment: Eu uso o método save() do JpaRepository, e minha entidade tem um parâmetro do tipo LocalDate e no MySQL o campo está com o tipo Date. Eu não faço nenhum tratamento antes de chamar o save() do JpaRepository, eu pego o objeto do jeito que ele vem do front e mando para o JpaRepository.

Comment: No caso seria isso aqui:

return repository.save( membro );

Obs: Esse objeto retornado pelo JpaRepository está com a data correta, porém no banco salva com a data -1

Comment: Você usa alguma anotação no Date da sua classe? Até onde eu saiba tem duas possiveis, @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) e 
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).
Da uma olhada nesse link e tenta formatar ela antes de ir pro banco pra ver se resolve.https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-date-time

Comment: Nesse link que você me mandou diz que as classes do pacote java.time.* não necessitam de anotação. Eu estou usando LocalDate.

Comment: Quando eu usava o hibernate eu não usava o util.Date e dava tudo certo. Seria tranquilo pra você testar com Calendar?

@Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar dataNascimento;

Comment: Se for dificil pra voce usar o Calendar, usa o Date com a anotação acima pra testar.

Comment: Acho que consegui resolver. Encontrei esses dois parâmetros para colocar na string de conexão ao BD: useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo. E também usei a properties user.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo no properties do Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Tente estas configurações no arquivo .properties:

```
# MYSQL
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost/MeuDataBase?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo
spring.datasource.username= MeuLogin
spring.datasource.password= MinhaSenha

# JPA
spring.jpa.database-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.open-in-view= true
spring.jpa.database= mysql
```